# Is is permissible to pass through a disinfection tunnel that sprays alcohol?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, travelling

Disinfection tunnels that spray chemicals on people in an attempt to kill bacteria and viruses are an increasingly common COVID countermeasure:

[image]

However, [many of these spray ethyl alcohol](https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/disinfection-tunnels-installed-in-some-places) (ethanol), and since you need to spend 10-30 seconds in the tunnel, you will breathe in some of this alcohol as well.  Is it permissible for a Muslim to use such a tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

There are new arguments by few scholars. Ahadith recall Muhammad performing ablution with nabidh (alcohol). Some argue that alcohols may have been used as medicines, disinfectants or santisiers in his days.  Quran mentions that alcohols have both some benefits and side effects (let me return with sura number). 
Many doctors including Muslims use medicinal alcohols during surgeries to kill bacteria, viruses and germs, as nothing else will do, for example e-coli.

Anyway, ethanol **evaporates**. Even if you do breathe in vapour of alcohol, it is not enough to make you intoxicant. 
Besides, it kills droplets of coronavirus/covid19 that could linger in air for 3 hours and longer on clothes or other surfaces.

I found something online [on islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/164448/what-is-the-ruling-on-praying-in-clothes-that-are-perfumed-with-alcohol-based-fragrances).

> Majmoo‘ Fataawa al-Shaykh al-‘Uthaymeen, 11/252
>
> Shaykh Muhammad ibn ‘Uthaymeen was also asked:
>
> "If it is proven that a perfume contains alcohol, can a person put it
>   on his clothing and go out to pray?"
>
> He answered:
>
> "It should be noted that pure alcohol is not najis and it does not
>   have to be washed from the clothing or the body. Once you understand
>   that, you will know that perfumes that contain alcohol, even if the
>   ratio is high, are not najis. "